# Matlab extracting data from excel

Tags: excel, matlab, variables

I have to read data from one column of excel where begins from A3 an incrementing like this:

```
0,-4.687500e-04,
1,-4.687500e-04,
2,-3.125000e-04,
3,-3.125000e-04,
4,1.562500e-04,
.
.
.
```

Number of data set is about 1400.
How can I extract and save sequence number and the variable between the commas seperately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the textscan command and set the ',' as delimiter.

```
filename = %name of the file;
delimiter = {','};
startRow = 3;
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
formatSpec = '%f%f[^\n\r]';
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType','string', 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine','\r\n');
fclose(fileID);
```